# error: no such device; grub rescue. when trying to boot

Tags: 12.04, boot

So I bought a brand new hard drive and put Ubuntu 12.04 on it. 
Then I decided to replace it with Windows 7, and I overwrote the entire Ubuntu partition.
Now I am wanting to set up Dual Boot, but when I try to boot with the Ubuntu Live CD I get the following error:

```
error: no such device: 3807..
grub rescue
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.. I don't understand what is going on and I can not even boot the Ubuntu Live CD.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Sry for my English.

Ubuntu Live CD doesn't matter what is stored on the hard disc. Because you see problem with grub, Live CD doesn't start. Check BIOS if is set start from CD/DVD.

Then follow this [repair grub](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/05/reinstall-recover-grub-from-ubuntu-12-04-live-cd-usb/) or google terms like "ubuntu grub repair from live cd"

Comment: But its not a problem with the live cd because I can boot it with ubuntu on other machines just fine.. Its something with my laptop

Answer (score 0):

if you overwrite on ubuntu part , you cant get dual boot (only windows) and you had to delete grub loader.

basiclly , delete all parts , setup windows (make 2 part , one of them for ubuntu ) after install ubuntu other part . that's it .